# Could someone be nice enough to add windows-phone-8.1 as a tag to superuser.com?

Tags: support, retag-request, tags

I haven't enough rep. The windows-phone-8 tag exists but 8.1 not.

Answer (score 9):

I'm willing to add the tag but first I wouldn't mind knowing whether your question is relating to interfacing Windows Phone with a computer or if it is solely to do with mobile phones.

Per the help centre [mobile phones are off topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> it is **not about**:
>
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer**

If you are asking specifically about Windows Phone use and problems then you will get better support at the [Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) site.